# how to save all dropdowns values from php foreach loop in local storage?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my cart i have my products added, there are stored in sessions.

[image]

I want to store my selected option from all dropdown when the page is refreshed.

I need to refresh my page so my sessions can be updated so i can post in my database all the updated values.
What is wrong...

*if i select an option for the first row of my product it saves in local storage.but when i select another product option from other row,it overwrites the local storage,so my local storage is saving only one option,and when selected other option from other products it is rewriting my only one save option in local storage.i have to save multiple option.*

Without refresh what happens is...

lets say that i've selected 1 cushion in my gallery.

So in my cart this cushion will be 1 product, and if i add two more by clicking plus button and then click on confirm order,it will post in my DB the value of 1.

But not 3.
So my page needs to refresh, so for that i need to save all dropdown selection so i can refresh the page.

So far i tried to save it,but it saves the first row of my cart.
This is what i tried...

```
$(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('fabric')) {
        $(".fabric option").eq(localStorage.getItem('fabric')).prop('selected', true);
    }

    $(".fabric").on('change', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('fabric', $('option:selected', this).index());
    });
});

$(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('size')) {
        $(".size option").eq(localStorage.getItem('size')).prop('selected', true);
    }

    $(".size").on('change', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('size', $('option:selected', this).index());
    });
});
```

this is my [foreach loop](http://pastebin.com/38Jp1D6S) if needed to understand it better.

this script below is not important for this question,but it shows how i am handling my dropdowns to make ajax get values based on dropdown selection using data attribute.

[script that gets cost and subtotal](http://pastebin.com/9Aw9K0kY)

Comment: First of all, localStorage isn't PHP. As its name obviously indicates, it's a LOCAL (client-side) storage. To update your DB, you have to submit a form or use ajax. I see none of this in the code you provided.

Comment: i know that,but i am trying to save selected options from my dropdowns,and i tried to use local storage,i posted the script that i used.

Comment: i want to use local storage to save all dropdown,but my dropdowns are overwriting

Comment: Okay... So when you refresh, previous values aren't there ? If so, try to remove `, this` from `$('option:selected', this).index()`... ... Try `localStorage.setItem('size', $(this).find('option:selected').index());`

Comment: if i select an option for the first row of my product it saves in local storage.but when i select another product option from other row,it overwrites the local storage,so my local storage is saving only one option,and when selected other option from other products it is rewriting my only one save option in local storage.i have to save multiple options

Comment: Haaa!!! I finally understand the issue now. I will try an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... Took a liitle time, but you will like my solution (I think).

We have to set storage row by row...
So an `.each()` loop has to be done on product rows.
We use the `index` of the `.each()` as a part of the storage name to ensure no overwriting.

Given this HTML that I made just for this example:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- other elements like img etc... -->

    <select class="fabric">
        <option>jeans</option>
        <option>leather</option>
        <option>cotton</option>
    </select>

    <select class="size">
        <option>small</option>
        <option>medium</option>
        <option>large</option>
    </select>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <!-- other elements like img etc... -->

    <select class="fabric">
        <option>jeans</option>
        <option>leather</option>
        <option>cotton</option>
    </select>

    <select class="size">
        <option>small</option>
        <option>medium</option>
        <option>large</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
$(function() {

    $(".row").each(function(index){

        // Fabric selection
        if (localStorage.getItem('row_'+index+'_fabric')) {
            $(this).find('.fabric option').prop('selected', false).eq(localStorage.getItem('row_'+index+'_fabric')).prop('selected', true);
            console.log("Row#"+index+" get-fabric: "+localStorage.getItem('row_'+index+'_fabric'));
        }

        $(this).find(".fabric").on('change', function() {
            localStorage.setItem('row_'+index+'_fabric', $(this).find('option:selected').index());
            console.log("Row#"+index+" set-fabric: "+$(this).find('option:selected').index());
        });


        // Size selection
        if (localStorage.getItem('row_'+index+'_size')) {
            $(this).find('.size option').prop('selected', false).eq(localStorage.getItem('row_'+index+'_size')).prop('selected', true);
            console.log("Row#"+index+" get-size: "+localStorage.getItem('row_'+index+'_size'));
        }

        $(this).find(".size").on('change', function() {
            localStorage.setItem('row_'+index+'_size', $(this).find('option:selected').index());
            console.log("Row#"+index+" set size: "+$(this).find('option:selected').index());
        });
    });
});
```

Try it on [**this CodePen!**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/QKkmXk?editors=1011)
*(Change the selects and hit "Run" to refresh)*

Comment: Louys thx so much! it works fine now, you just saved me, i been trying to save all this for a month,I am  learning by my self php,jquery i'm still a noob on it,so i take a lot of time to develop something

Comment: Learning takes time and efforts... Since your code was real close to what you needed, I think that you're on the right track ;)